# Side by side ggplot bar plots with shared legend and different x-axis variables

Tags: r, ggplot2

Counts of disaster reporting from agriculture in Vermont based on year and by county from 2012-2020. I  would like to plot these two plots of [by county](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m9IEh.png) and [by year](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jtWHx.png) together with a common legend. Note the x-axes are different and the colors don't match for the shared variables of the two legends.

While both 'by Year' and 'by County' share the same number of variables in their original dataset, because I want to subset the variables that have at least 3 or more occurrences for any given year or county, only 3 variables remain for 'By County' while 'By Year' has those same three plus an additional 3.

I searched stack for an answer but no unique solution, any ideas on how to achieve the desired output is appreciated.

Here is the data:

```
df1<-structure(list(County = c("Addison", "Addison", "Addison", "Bennington", 
"Bennington", "Bennington", "Caledonia", "Caledonia", "Caledonia", 
"Chittenden", "Chittenden", "Chittenden", "Essex", "Essex", "Essex", 
"Franklin", "Franklin", "Franklin", "Grand Isle", "Grand Isle", 
"Grand Isle", "Lamoille", "Lamoille", "Lamoille", "Orange", "Orange", 
"Orange", "Orleans", "Orleans", "Orleans", "Rutland", "Rutland", 
"Rutland", "Washington", "Washington", "Washington", "Windham", 
"Windham", "Windham", "Windsor", "Windsor", "Windsor"), Type = c("Drought", 
"Frost & Cold Below\nNormal Temperatures", "Flooding &\nExcessive Rain", 
"Drought", "Frost & Cold Below\nNormal Temperatures", "Flooding &\nExcessive Rain", 
"Drought", "Frost & Cold Below\nNormal Temperatures", "Flooding &\nExcessive Rain", 
"Drought", "Frost & Cold Below\nNormal Temperatures", "Flooding &\nExcessive Rain", 
"Drought", "Frost & Cold Below\nNormal Temperatures", "Flooding &\nExcessive Rain", 
"Drought", "Frost & Cold Below\nNormal Temperatures", "Flooding &\nExcessive Rain", 
"Drought", "Frost & Cold Below\nNormal Temperatures", "Flooding &\nExcessive Rain", 
"Drought", "Frost & Cold Below\nNormal Temperatures", "Flooding &\nExcessive Rain", 
"Drought", "Frost & Cold Below\nNormal Temperatures", "Flooding &\nExcessive Rain", 
"Drought", "Frost & Cold Below\nNormal Temperatures", "Flooding &\nExcessive Rain", 
"Drought", "Frost & Cold Below\nNormal Temperatures", "Flooding &\nExcessive Rain", 
"Drought", "Frost & Cold Below\nNormal Temperatures", "Flooding &\nExcessive Rain", 
"Drought", "Frost & Cold Below\nNormal Temperatures", "Flooding &\nExcessive Rain", 
"Drought", "Frost & Cold Below\nNormal Temperatures", "Flooding &\nExcessive Rain"
), Count = c(4L, 3L, 7L, 7L, 4L, 7L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 7L, 
5L, 6L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 7L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 1L, 
1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 5L), layer = c("By County", 
"By County", "By County", "By County", "By County", "By County", 
"By County", "By County", "By County", "By County", "By County", 
"By County", "By County", "By County", "By County", "By County", 
"By County", "By County", "By County", "By County", "By County", 
"By County", "By County", "By County", "By County", "By County", 
"By County", "By County", "By County", "By County", "By County", 
"By County", "By County", "By County", "By County", "By County", 
"By County", "By County", "By County", "By County", "By County", 
"By County"), Year = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA
)), row.names = c(NA, -42L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))

df2<-structure(list(Year = c("2012", "2012", "2012", "2012", "2012", 
"2012", "2013", "2013", "2013", "2013", "2013", "2013", "2014", 
"2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2015", "2015", "2015", 
"2015", "2015", "2015", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", 
"2016", "2017", "2017", "2017", "2017", "2017", "2017", "2018", 
"2018", "2018", "2018", "2018", "2018", "2019", "2019", "2019", 
"2019", "2019", "2019", "2020", "2020", "2020", "2020", "2020", 
"2020"), Type = c("Heat, Excessive Heat,\nHigh Temp, Low Humidty", 
"Wind, High Winds", "Hail", "Drought", "Frost & Cold Below\nNormal Temperatures", 
"Flooding &\nExcessive Rain", "Heat, Excessive Heat,\nHigh Temp, Low Humidty", 
"Wind, High Winds", "Hail", "Drought", "Frost & Cold Below\nNormal Temperatures", 
"Flooding &\nExcessive Rain", "Heat, Excessive Heat,\nHigh Temp, Low Humidty", 
"Wind, High Winds", "Hail", "Drought", "Frost & Cold Below\nNormal Temperatures", 
"Flooding &\nExcessive Rain", "Heat, Excessive Heat,\nHigh Temp, Low Humidty", 
"Wind, High Winds", "Hail", "Drought", "Frost & Cold Below\nNormal Temperatures", 
"Flooding &\nExcessive Rain", "Heat, Excessive Heat,\nHigh Temp, Low Humidty", 
"Wind, High Winds", "Hail", "Drought", "Frost & Cold Below\nNormal Temperatures", 
"Flooding &\nExcessive Rain", "Heat, Excessive Heat,\nHigh Temp, Low Humidty", 
"Wind, High Winds", "Hail", "Drought", "Frost & Cold Below\nNormal Temperatures", 
"Flooding &\nExcessive Rain", "Heat, Excessive Heat,\nHigh Temp, Low Humidty", 
"Wind, High Winds", "Hail", "Drought", "Frost & Cold Below\nNormal Temperatures", 
"Flooding &\nExcessive Rain", "Heat, Excessive Heat,\nHigh Temp, Low Humidty", 
"Wind, High Winds", "Hail", "Drought", "Frost & Cold Below\nNormal Temperatures", 
"Flooding &\nExcessive Rain", "Heat, Excessive Heat,\nHigh Temp, Low Humidty", 
"Wind, High Winds", "Hail", "Drought", "Frost & Cold Below\nNormal Temperatures", 
"Flooding &\nExcessive Rain"), Count = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 3L, 
0L, 0L, 5L, 5L, 0L, 0L, 38L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 10L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 
3L, 8L, 0L, 3L, 8L, 3L, 0L, 9L, 10L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 
4L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 19L, 19L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 24L, 0L, 0L), layer = c("By Year", "By Year", "By Year", 
"By Year", "By Year", "By Year", "By Year", "By Year", "By Year", 
"By Year", "By Year", "By Year", "By Year", "By Year", "By Year", 
"By Year", "By Year", "By Year", "By Year", "By Year", "By Year", 
"By Year", "By Year", "By Year", "By Year", "By Year", "By Year", 
"By Year", "By Year", "By Year", "By Year", "By Year", "By Year", 
"By Year", "By Year", "By Year", "By Year", "By Year", "By Year", 
"By Year", "By Year", "By Year", "By Year", "By Year", "By Year", 
"By Year", "By Year", "By Year", "By Year", "By Year", "By Year", 
"By Year", "By Year", "By Year"), County = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, -54L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

Here is the code:

```
# library(ggplot2)
# library(RColorBrewer)
# library(sjPlot)
# library(tidyr)
# library(viridis)

set_theme(
  geom.outline.color = "antiquewhite4", 
  geom.outline.size = .5, 
  geom.label.size = 1.5,
  geom.label.color = "black",
  title.color = "black", 
  title.size = 1.5, 
  title.align = 'center',
  # axis.angle.x = 90, 
  axis.textcolor = "black", 
  axis.textsize = 1.15,
  base = theme_bw(),
)

p1<-ggplot(df1)+
  geom_bar(aes(x=County, y=Count, fill=Type), stat="identity") +
  # scale_fill_brewer(palette="PuRd") +
  scale_fill_viridis(discrete = TRUE) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 1, hjust=1), legend.key.height=unit(.75, "cm"))

p1

p2<-ggplot(df2)+
  geom_bar(aes(x=Year, y=Count, fill=Type), stat="identity") +
  # scale_fill_brewer(palette="PuRd") +
  scale_fill_viridis(discrete = TRUE) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 1, hjust=1), legend.key.height=unit(.75, "cm"))

p2
```

Comment: Try setting the `limits` in `scale_fill_viridis()` to whatever categories of `Type` you want to have represented in both plots. I'm not sure what other categories are in `df1`, but here's what adding an "Other" category in your first plot would look like: `limits = c("Drought", "Frost & Cold Below\nNormal Temperatures", "Flooding &\nExcessive Rain", "Other")`

Comment: `patchwork` might be worth exploring

Comment: Thank you @aosmith I can use ```scale_fill_viridis(discrete = TRUE, limits = c("Drought", "Frost & Cold Below\nNormal Temperatures", "Flooding &\nExcessive Rain", "Other1", 'Other2', 'Other3'))``` to make three dummy factors, so the number of factors plotted in 'By County' match 'By Year', then using the grid.arrange() code Heidi posted works.

Answer (score 0):

I tried gridExtra with your code and it seemed to do the trick

```
library(gridExtra)
p3 <- grid.arrange(arrangeGrob(p1 + theme(legend.position="none"),
                           p2 + theme(legend.position="right"),
                           nrow=1),nrow=2,heights=c(10, 1))
```

The issues I see after are changing the legend title and perhaps removing/hiding one of the y-axis labels (edit: Now I can see that the axes are not the same)

Comment: Thank you for the response unfortunately this does not solve my problem because the colors in the legend don't work with the 'By County' plot